# How prevent \maketitle refusing floats on title page? (pdfLaTeX)

Tags: floats, revtex

everyone, I am writing a paper and I want to have a Figure on the first (title) page, but after using `\maketitle` this page refuses all floats even though there is a plenty of space for them to fit in. The usual placement specifiers `[h!]` or `[H`] didn't work, of course.

I noticed there is a command `\suppressfloats[t]` in the `\maketitle definition, so I tried to redefine it without this command, that also didn't help.

I also tried "hard"-placing the figure, but that doesn't work well with the two-column layout.

Does anybody have any suggestions for a workaround? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the small working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,pra,linenumber,showpacs,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Revolutionary article} 
\author{T. H. E. Author}
\affiliation{Great Institute, Big City, Small Country}
\author{H. I. S. Friend}
\affiliation{O.K. University, Small Town, Huge Country}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[h!]
  \begin{tabular}{lcclc}
a) &{\framebox[5cm]{}} & \quad & b) & {\framebox[5cm]{}} \\
c) &{\framebox[5cm]{}} & \quad & d) & {\framebox[5cm]{}} 
  \end{tabular},
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you want the image placed? Just below the title before the two-column text starts? That would be about the only safe (sane?) place to put it.

Comment: You are using a journal class, so it's normally best just to accept things come out 'how they do': the journal will not normally allow you to hack about with their design decisions.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a `\maketitle` problem. The class you are using doesn't permit you to place floats in the first page.

Since it seems to be so well hardcoded, I think that if you are using that document class, you should accept it as a requirement for the journal.

But if you really want to go against their directives, you can do the following.

Load the `capt-of` package so  you can define a `\caption` for non-floating objects (`\captionof{figure}` in this case), remove the `tabular` from the `figure*` environment and insert it in a `center` environment

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lcclc}
a) &{\framebox[5cm]{}} & \quad & b) & {\framebox[5cm]{}} \\
c) &{\framebox[5cm]{}} & \quad & d) & {\framebox[5cm]{}}
  \end{tabular},
  \captionof{figure}{Caption}
\end{center}
```

after having issued

```
\onecolumngrid
```

After that, issue

```
\twocolumngrid
```

to restore the normal behavior.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,pra,linenumber,showpacs,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\title{Revolutionary article}
\author{T. H. E. Author}
\affiliation{Great Institute, Big City, Small Country}
\author{H. I. S. Friend}
\affiliation{O.K. University, Small Town, Huge Country}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\onecolumngrid

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lcclc}
a) &{\framebox[5cm]{}} & \quad & b) & {\framebox[5cm]{}} \\
c) &{\framebox[5cm]{}} & \quad & d) & {\framebox[5cm]{}}
  \end{tabular},
  \captionof{figure}{Caption}
\end{center}

\twocolumngrid

\lipsum[1]  

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I tried almost the same approach before, but it didn't occur to me to use \onecolumngrid and \twocolumngrid, so the figure was shifted to the right column with the caption in the left one. And of course, I generally agree that I should not mess around with the journal document class, but this is for supplementary material, which contain one short paragraph and then only figures, so it is sensible to force them to appear on the title page. I've seen that done previously in other papers with supp. material.

Comment: @lixpas You're welcome. Glad it helped.